# Cannot access website after changing ownership recusively

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, webserver

In my web server, I intentionally changed ownership of the `public_html` folder recursively using `chown user:user -R public_html` command. Now i cant access my website. It throws an `403 forbidden` error while accessing.

[image]

I know the issue is with `.htaccess` file and I tried changing ownership to root user back again and changing file permission to `755` and `644` back and forth. Still no progress. Please can someone look into this. What is the cause for this and what will be the solution?

Comment: You should change the ownership to `www-data:www-data` and all directories should be `0755` and files should be `0644` by default.  If you want the `user` to be able to write / overwrite files .. You need to add them to the www-data `group` and visa versa ..

Comment: Also it helps to remove your `.htaccess` file completely when testing ..  Adding it only when you're "set up" and satisfied with your configuration ..

Comment: it says `chown: invalid user: ‘www-data:www-data’` error

Comment: Eventhough i removed `.htaccess` file it is not loading

Comment: And you used: `chown -R www–data:www-data public_html`. Notice that there is a difference between a `hyphen` and a `dash` ..

Comment: What user account is your http server running under? What distribution is that? Different distributions use different setups. And where is that "public_html" folder located? Sounds a bit like this is _not_ the usual system wide document root folder, but that you are using the user module?

Comment: Thanx @Zak and @arkascha for helping me out. The issue was with the ownership of the `public_html` folder. After changing the ownership of the folder to `user:nobody` it worked as usual. Thanks again for helping me out.